# calculate the average for the given assignment and will return the average. PYTHON

Tags: python

I've been writing  this code, but it seem to work.

```
This function takes two parameters, the entire list of students and an integer
    indicating which assignment (0, 1, 2 or 3) you wish to find the average for.
    You will need to add the two parameters to the function
    declaration.

    The function will calculate the average for the given assignment and will return the
    average.
```

this  is  my code:

```
def AverageAssignment(students, assignement_number):

    if assignement_number != range(0,3):
        return -999

    assignement_number= students[0][1]


    deno=0
    average=0
    n=len(students[0][1])

    for i in students:
        deno+=1
        average = sum(i[1][assignement_number])


        
        
students = [('Jane',[70,80,90,100]),('xinrong',[60,50,30,40]),('sima',[100,70,30,100])]
#AverageAssignment(students,0)
```

thank you

I was expecting the average of  the assignment number( just the formula)

Comment: There seems to be no question here. Although, you say: `"it seem to work"` - how do you know that?

Comment: Your integer *assignement_number* will never be equal to a *range()*

Answer (score 1):

Erros I can see:

Your assignment_number will never equal to a range. What you probably want to do is `assignment_number in range(0,3)`.

Can't see why you would `assignement_number= students[0][1]` this will always overwrite it with Jane's scores

Answer (score 1):

Does this code solve your problem?

```
def AverageAssignment(students,assignment_no):
    try:
        scores = [student[1][assignment_no] for student in students]
        return (sum(scores)/len(scores))
    except IndexError:
        return -999

    

students = [('Jane',[70,80,90,100]),('xinrong',[60,50,30,40]),('sima',[100,70,30,100])]

assignment = 0
print(AverageAssignment(students,assignment))

assignment = 1
print(AverageAssignment(students,assignment))

assignment = 2
print(AverageAssignment(students,assignment))

assignment = 3
print(AverageAssignment(students,assignment))

assignment = 4
print(AverageAssignment(students,assignment))
```

Rather than checking to see if the assignment number is between 0 and 3 (What if there are 5 assignments, or 10, or 100?) we just catch the error if we try to access a score that doesn't exist.

I create a list `scores` which will contain the score for each student for the specified assignment.
Once I've got that, I divide the sum of the scores but the length of the scores list to give the average.

Following your example, the function returns -999 if an invalid assignment number is used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in *sum()* function in conjunction with a generator as follows:

```
students = [('Jane',[70,80,90,100]),('xinrong',[60,50,30,40]),('sima',[100,70,30,100])]

def get_average(slist, assignment):
    return sum(score[assignment] for _, score in slist) / len(slist)

print(get_average(students, 1))
```

**Output:**

```
66.66666666666667
```

**Note:**

There is no defence in this code for bad indexes (*assignment*)